# Python based finite element solver for 2D manifold embedded in 3 dimensional space

Tags: python, mesh, differential-equations, eigenvalue, finite-element-analysis

I am trying to use the finite element method to solve the Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue problem on a surface (i.e., a 2D dimensional manifold) embedded in 3-dimensional space, for example, the boundary of a sphere or torus. I managed to generate the triangular mesh (its points and triangles) using the Pyvista library.

```
points = [[-2.5819006 -6.5754533 -2.0017405]
 [-2.6988158 -6.5754533 -1.9960535]
 [-2.5819006 -6.604572  -1.9960535]
 ...
 [ 1.4294114  7.86527    1.7230791]
 [ 2.2316737  7.86527    1.6120211]
 [ 3.0339363  7.86527    1.388944 ]]
```

```
cells = [[   0    1    2]
 [   2    3    0]
 [   4    5    6]
 ...
 [ 925 1144  924]
 [1145 1144  925]
 [ 909 1145  925]]
```

Now I am looking for a simple finite element solver.

Usually, I use the scikit-fem library which works well in situations with flat 2-dimensional triangular meshes or tetrahedral meshes in 3D shapes. However, it can not handle triangular meshes of 2-dimensional surfaces in 3-dimensional space. Which package can easily solve the Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue problem for such meshes?

Comment: Laplace-Beltrami ev problem == ev problem of the Laplacian on a general manifold?

Comment: What is the out-of-plane behavior of the 2D manifold?  Can you approximate it with thin shell elements?  I don't know whether the bending behavior of plate/shell elements are appropriate for your problem.  A 2D planar element assumes zero displacement perpendicular to the element.  I'll bet that's not appropriate for your problem.